# Inequality in metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

For a point $x$ and a non-empty subset $A$ of a metric space $(X, d)$,
define \begin{align}\inf\left\{ d(x,a):a\in A\right\}\end{align}

Prove that if $y$ is another point in $X$ then $$d(x,A)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,A)$$

Comment: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

Then by the definition of the infimum, $d(y,A)+\varepsilon$ is not a lower bound for $\{d(y,a)\mid a \in A\}$ (or it would contradict the maximality of $d(y,A)$) so there is some $a_0 \in A$ so that $d(y,a_0) < d(y,A) + \varepsilon$. It follows that $$d(x,A) \le d(x,a_0) \le d(x,y) + d(y,a_0) < d(x,y) + d(y,A) + \varepsilon$$

As this holds for arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ we have that $d(x,A) \le d(x,y) + d(y,A)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** For every $a\in A$, by triangle inequality, $$d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a).$$ What's next?